# How to get route parameter of Get from Post Action in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

I have two methods, one Get and one related Post.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string id){...}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model){...}
```

In the Post Method, I wish to get the id parameter of the Get method. Is it possible?

Currently, what i am doing is passing the id as form parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, MyModel model){...}
```

Any other method?

Comment: Is `id` a property of `MyModel`?

Comment: no, it is actually not related to MyModel, but your answer is very great which give me inspiration, I suppose I can put it as part of MyModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the ID would be part of your Model that is being edited. You were able to retrieve the correct model in the GET Edit method using the ID, and hence, it is likely part of your MyModel model parameter of the POST Edit method.

As long as your MyModel class contains that Id, then posting it from the view should bind it correctly.

M